# CS50 pset3 — game of fifteen

Tags: c, sorting, cs50, linear-search

The code given below is an answer of the problem set 3 from CS50.
Please have a look at functions: `init`,
                                 `draw`,
                                 `move`,
                                 `won` 
and suggest some improvements that I can make.
Actually I am getting some errors that I don't understand.

```
/**
 * fifteen.c
 *
 * Implements Game of Fifteen (generalized to d x d).
 *
 * Usage: fifteen d
 *
 * whereby the board's dimensions are to be d x d,
 * where d must be in [DIM_MIN,DIM_MAX]
 *
 * Note that usleep is obsolete, but it offers more granularity than
 * sleep and is simpler to use than nanosleep; `man usleep` for more.
 */

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// constants
#define DIM_MIN 3
#define DIM_MAX 9

// board
int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];

// dimensions
int d;

// prototypes
void clear(void);
void greet(void);
void init(void);
void draw(void);
bool move(int tile);
bool won(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: fifteen d\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // ensure valid dimensions
    d = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (d < DIM_MIN || d > DIM_MAX)
    {
        printf("Board must be between %i x %i and %i x %i, inclusive.\n",
             DIM_MIN, DIM_MIN, DIM_MAX, DIM_MAX);
        return 2;
    }

     // open log
    FILE *file = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
         return 3;
    }

    // greet user with instructions
    greet();

    // initialize the board
    init();

    // accept moves until game is won
    while (true)
    {
        // clear the screen
        clear();

        // draw the current state of the board
        draw();

        // log the current state of the board (for testing)
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
            {
                fprintf(file, "%i", board[i][j]);
                if (j < d - 1)
                {
                    fprintf(file, "|");
                }
            }
            fprintf(file, "\n");
        }
        fflush(file);

        // check for win
        if (won())
        {
            printf("ftw!\n");
            break;
        }

        // prompt for move
        printf("Tile to move: ");
        int tile = get_int();

       // quit if user inputs 0 (for testing)
       if (tile == 0)
        {
           break;
        }

        // log move (for testing)
        fprintf(file, "%i\n", tile);
        fflush(file);

         // move if possible, else report illegality
        if (!move(tile))
        {
            printf("\nIllegal move.\n");
            usleep(500000);
        }

         // sleep thread for animation's sake
         usleep(500000);
     }

     // close log
     fclose(file);

     // success
     return 0;
}

/**
  * Clears screen using ANSI escape sequences.
 */
void clear(void)
{
    printf("\033[2J");
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", 0, 0);
}

/**
 * Greets player.
 */
void greet(void)
{
     clear();
     printf("WELCOME TO GAME OF FIFTEEN\n");
     usleep(2000000);
}

/**
  * Initializes the game's board with tiles numbered 1 through d*d - 1
  * (i.e., fills 2D array with values but does not actually print them).  
  */
  void init(void)
  {
     int board[4][4];
     int d;
     do
     {
        printf("enter the size of the board\n");
        scanf("%i",&d);  
     }while(d <= 4);
    printf("enter the values in the grid\n");
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<d;j++)
          {
            scanf("%i\n",&board[i][j]); // set tile's value
          }
    }
      if(d%2 == 0)
     {
         int temp;
         temp = board[3][1];
         board[3][1] = board[3][2];
         board[3][2] = temp;
     }


}

 /**
  * Prints the board in its current state.
  */
 void draw(void)
 {
    int d;

    for(int i=0;i<d-1;i++)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<d;j++)
         {
             printf("%2i",board[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
     }
     do
     {
         for(int j=0;j<d-1;j++)
         {
             printf("%2i",board[int i][int j]);
          }   
      } while (int i=d-1);
      char board[d-1][d-1] = ' ';
      printf("%c \n", board[d-1][d-1]);
 }

  /**
   * If tile borders empty space, moves tile and returns true, else
    * returns false. 
    */
 bool move(int tile)
 {
      int d;
     for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<d;j++)
         {
            if(board[i][j] == tile)
             {
                 return board[i][j];
             }
         }
     }  
    int temp;
    temp = board[2][2];
    board[2][2] = board[int i][int j];
    board[int i][int j] = temp; 
 }

/**
 * Returns true if game is won (i.e., board is in winning configuration), 
 * else false.
 */
bool won(void)
{
    // TODO

    for(i=0;i<d;i++)
     {
         for(j=0;j<d;j++)
         {
            if(a[i][j] < a[i+1][j+1])
            {
                return true;
                break;
             }
             else{
                 return false;
                 break;
                 }
         }
     }
 }
```

I am getting this error, which I am not able to solve.

> > format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'dependent type'

Comment: Regarding your opening paragraph, Stack Overflow is not [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) The only on-topic question for SO here is what that error means. You should edit the post and its title to reflect that.

Comment: Please post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and give the full error. Also, not everyone will know what "CS50" is, but truth be told it's not really relevant to the question, so I'd recommend deleting the references to it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `init()` function, you initialised `board[4][4]` but a board of custom size as required is already used and you need to keep the indexing in terms of d and not use 4 or any other fixed board size.

Also in the `init()` function, you don't need to manually input the numbers for the tiles. Try using a variable(integer and assign it to the required tile and increment that variable before assigning it to the next tile.
Accordingly, there will be changes in the condition which checks if d is even or odd.

The `draw()` function seems to be fine.

The `move()` function has some problems. `return board[i][j];` is invalid as the function has return type bool. The logic seems to be incorrect. Check the walkthroughs if you haven't already.

In the `won()` function, using `break;` statement after return is not needed. Also if you carefully check the condition you have written in the if condition, it doesn't check each variable with the next in the same row or the next in the next row, but checks each variable's diagonally next variable even if it does not exist.

I would recommend you to re-watch the lecture videos, shorts and walkthroughs to get a better understanding of the code and C in general.